# How to go fullscreen from picture in picture?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, picture-in-picture

I try to implement this feature when a user using pip(picture in picture) is there an option or an API to go fullscreen from the pip window ie if the user closes the window or stop playing the video full-screen video should appear now I know chrome will prevent this fullscreen mode without user gesture but is there an inbuilt API for that inside pip

```
     video.addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', () => {
            console.log('Left PIP....');
            this.makeCamFullScreen()

        })
   makeCamFullScreen = () => {
       let fullscreen = this.fullscreen;
       fullscreen.requestFullscreen()


    };
```

my code (When a user closes the pip window it try to go full screen but i am getting an error)

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.